# How can I find the square root of the product of two matrices?

Tags: matrices

I want to know why $X^{-1}(XY)^{1/2}=X^{-1/2}(X^{1/2} Y X^{1/2})^{1/2} X^{-1/2}$, where $X$ and $Y$ are symmetric and positive definite matrices.

Comment: The square root does not "operate" (this is the terminology of functional anayisis) on the ring of matrices. it does just on a subset. I suppose this is so with your conditions

Comment: Why isn't the answer accepted? (Please delete this comment if you decide to accept the answer)

Answer (score 0):

Take an equivalent relation (move the $X$'s from right to left)
$$
LHS:=X^{-1/2}(XY)^{1/2}X^{1/2}\color{red}{\stackrel{?}=}(X^{1/2}YX^{1/2})^{1/2}=:RHS
$$
and square to get $LHS^2=RHS^2$. Provided that $(\cdot)^{1/2}$ denotes the usual unique square root of diagonalizable matrices with positive eigenvalues, this implies that $LHS=RHS$.

Comment: @Ramanujan A matrix does not need to be symmetric in order to have a square root. $XY$ is diagonalizable and has positive eigenvalues, so if $XY=ZDZ^{-1}$ is a diagonalization of $XY$, $(XY)^{1/2}=ZD^{1/2}Z^{-1}$.